# Webpage not showing scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css

My webpage is not showing option of scrolling... while page expands downwards, things get hidden from my screen.

**style.css**

```
body {
font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
font color:#FFFFFF;
font-size: 16px;
font-style: normal;
line-height: normal;
font-weight: normal;
font-variant: normal;
background-image:url(images/Red-Black-HD-Wallpapers.jpg);
background-attachment:scroll;
}
```

Here comes my form and I used some style tag in between the code. As I am new to this, please help me come out from here.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
     <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Vender 1</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
     </head>

    <body>
    <div align="center" id="mainWrapper">
     <?php include "header.php";?>
      <div id="pageContent"><br />
     <div align="right" style=" padding-top:50px; margin-right:32px; color:#FF0000"><a style="color:#FF0000" href="vender1.php#inventoryForm">+ Add New Inventory Item</a></div>
     <div align="left" style="margin-left:24px;">
     <h2  style="color:#FF0000">Inventory list</h2>
     <?php echo $product_list; ?>
   </div>
   <hr />
    <a name="inventoryForm" id="inventoryForm"></a>
   <h3  style="color:#FF0000">
   &darr; Add New Inventory Item Form &darr;
   </h3>
   <form action="vender1.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="myForm" id="myform" method="post">
  <table width="90%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6">
  <tr>
    <td width="20%" align="right" style="color:#FF0000">Product Name</td>
    <td width="80%"><label>
      <input name="product_name" type="text" id="product_name" size="64" />
    </label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right"  style="color:#FF0000">Product Price</td>
    <td><label>
      $
      <input name="price" type="text" id="price" size="12" />
    </label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right" style="color:#FF0000">Category</td>
    <td><label>
      <select name="category" id="category">
      <option value="Clothing">Clothing</option>
      </select>
    </label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right"  style="color:#FF0000">Subcategory</td>
    <td><select name="subcategory" id="subcategory">
    <option value=""></option>
      <option value="Hats">Hats</option>
      <option value="Pants">Pants</option>
      <option value="Shirts">Shirts</option>
      </select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right"  style="color:#FF0000">Product Details</td>
    <td><label>
      <textarea name="details" id="details" cols="64" rows="5"></textarea>
    </label></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><label>
      <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Add This Item Now" />
    </label></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
<br />
 <br />
 </div>
 <a href="logout.php">Log Out</a>

 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

I don't know how to get my scrolling. All css I used is included in my code.

Comment: If I put the code in [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/505gawrf/), it scrolls fine in both directions...

Comment: @komaldeepsinghchahal You mean my fiddle doesn't have scrollbars on your computer? It does here; [screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/6C3d6.png). What browser are you using, what platform etc.

Comment: i am using google chrome and simple making website through xampp server

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qvefb3cg/   this is code .. but i dont why it is happening here

Comment: Your fiddle behaves the same way as mine, i.e. with two scrollbars if you make the output pane small enough. Not sure what to say now.